# Деепричастный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Рассмотрев каталоги нескольких крупных предприятий отрасли (,) хочется, подобно критику, произнести...

Нужна ли запятая, если предложение безличное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Рассмотрев каталоги нескольких крупных предприятий отрасли, хочется, подобно критику, произнести...

**Запятая нужна, так как деепричастный оборот обособляется практически всегда**, за исключением того случая, когда деепричастие приобретает функцию наречия.

2) **Можно ли деепричастный оборот использовать в безличном предложении?** Думаю, что это как раз тот случай, который допускается.

Это безличное предложение обобщенного характера, где нет указания на конкретного производителя действия (правило, рекомендация, инструкция, **сентенция**). В состав такого безличного предложения обязательно должен входить инфинитив, например: Рассматривая данный вопрос, необходимо привлечь все имеющиеся документы".

3) **Непонятны рассуждения о причине и следствии,** так как здесь описываются две ситуации, связанные **временными отношениями**: "после рассмотрения каталогов".

**4) О виде деепричастия**

"В вашем примере употреблены сразу совершенный и несовершенный вид глаголов, т.е. несовпадение во времени действия глагола сказуемого и деепричастия"

Деепричастие несовершенного вида употребляется в том случае, если главное и дополнительное  действие происходят одновременно, **а деепричастие совершенного вида  – если действия происходят в разное время.** В препозиции деепричастие сов. вида обозначает предшествующее действие, а в постпозиции может обозначать последующее действие.

Вывод

Не стоит углубляться в теорию и искать там сложности, которых нет. В данном случае язык пытается нормировать **полезную для речи конструкцию**, которая имеет **ясный смысл и краткую форму** без существенных грамматических отклонений.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше написать "По рассмотрении...", поскольку (см. недавнюю тему о деепр. обороте) его корректность здесь спорна (а на мой взгляд, имеет место ошибка, поскольку этот оборот не свести к обстоятельству образа действия от общего источника действия - из-за причинной связи).

Comment: По-моему, все сформулировано вполне по правилам русского языка. Рассмотрев, хочется произнести...

Comment: Для меня не всё так просто. "Рассмотрев" здесь нельзя отнести к действию, выраженному безличным предложением, в отличие от напр. такого: "мне хотелось подобно критику, рассматривая этот материал страницу за страницей, критиковать и критиковать" (мне хотелось "критиковать, рассматривая" - действия выраженные глаголом и деепричастием имеют общий источник, выраженный в безличной форме;

Comment: в первой же фразе действие "рассмотрения" (причина) предшествует второму действию (следствию), исходящему от источника, обозначенного безлично, поэтому оно не может быть подчинено тому же источнику (причина не подчиняется следствию). 
Знаю, что есть либеральная тенденция не делать различия между одним и другим, но я такие выражения воспринимаю их как ошибку.

Comment: Аленка, действия глагола сказуемого и деепричастия должны совпадать. В вашем примере нестыковка во времени.

Comment: Значит, я в данном случае за либеральную тенденцию.

Answer (score 0):

Деепричастный оборот, как правило, обособляется (выделяется запятыми) независимо от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому: независимо от того предложение личное или безличное.

Однако обратите внимание: в вашем предложении, как указал Александр, действительно, содержится ошибка. В вашем примере употреблены сразу совершенный и несовершенный вид глаголов, т.е. несовпадение во времение действия глагола сказуемого и деепричастия.